Qt Clang-Tidy pipeline
I'm trying to create an azure pipeline to run clang-tidy to check my Qt code.
The file:
trigger:
- development

pool:
  vmImage: 'ubuntu-latest'

jobs:
- job: Lint
  displayName: 'Lint C++ code with Qt'
  steps:
    - task: UsePythonVersion@0
      inputs:
        versionSpec: '3.x'
        addToPath: true

    - script: |
        sudo apt-get update
        sudo apt-get install clang-tidy cppcheck -y
        sudo apt-get install qtchooser qt6-base-dev qt6-tools-dev -y
        sudo apt-get install libqt6bluetooth6 qt6-connectivity-dev -y
        sudo apt-get install libqt6serialport6 libqt6serialport6-dev -y

        export PATH=/usr/lib/qt6/bin/:$PATH
        export QT_SELECT=qt6

        sudo find /usr -name QtWidgets
        sudo find /usr -name QWidget

      displayName: 'Install Qt and linters'

    - script: |
        mkdir build
        cd build
        export PATH=/usr/lib/qt6/bin/:$PATH
        export QT_SELECT=qt6
        qmake ../project.pro
        make
      displayName: 'Build the project with qmake (or CMake)'

    - script: |
            find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs clang-tidy -p=build/
      displayName: 'Run clang-tidy with Qt support'

The last script part is what I'm struggling with. When I run it, the pipeline terminal comes back to me with:
error: 'QObject' file not found [clang-diagnostic-error] #include <QObject>
And not only for this QObject, but for many more such as QLabel, QWidget, QObject, QComboBox and name many more.
I tried this command as well:
QT_INCLUDE_PATHS="/usr/lib/qt6 /usr/lib/qt6/QtWidgets /usr/lib/qt6/QtCore"
find . -name "*.cpp" | xargs clang-tidy -p=build/ -- -I$QT_INCLUDE_PATHS

This, however, gave me:
Error: no input files specified.
USAGE: clang-tidy [options] <source0> [... <sourceN>]

What can I do to run clang-tidy with Qt code, or is my approach incorrect at all?

But try to follow your own advices to tools and see if those are correct. For example ... Aren't the files you mention not found usually in place like usr/include/qt6/QtWidgets ? If on your case as well then what is the point to suggest tools to search those in place like /usr/lib/qt6/QtWidgets ?

I have listened to your advice and ran some 'ls' commands. I found that these folders were located in '/usr/include/x86_64-linux/gnu/qt6.
Yet, using that as folder will not give me anything else than the same error.

OK, now you at least know where the files that are not found are actually located.  Next step is to take working examples from tutorials and see if you can reproduce those verbatim. Programming is not voodoo trying, it is very precise art.

What's the result if you build and run clang-tidy on your local machine with the same scripts?

Unfortunately, running clang-tidy on my local Windows machine so I can't compare

I am just wondering, is this the correct method of including those files since it gives me the --help list as well

Testing your yaml in my pipeline, I can't reproduce the issue. If you can run clang-tidy on your local Windows machine, I would suggest use Windows-latest image in the pipeline to have a working one. Then share the working yaml.
